# Date getTime() not updating

Tags: javascript, date, validation, timestamp

I have an application doing some HTTP requests, and every time I send a request to the API I need to send in the header a timestamp parameter, it must be a integer and the number should never be the same or below the previous.

So to handle this i am using a simple solution:

```
const timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
```

As you guys know this will always generate a number bigger than the previous one. But sometimes it simply doesnt refresh properly. I make a new request every 10 seconds but sometimes the number generated by the function is the same it was 10 seconds ago... How ???

So I need is a solution for this problem

PS.: I also tried using `Date.now()` and the same problem appears

Comment: what happens when you try "let timestamp" instead of "const timestamp"

Comment: I don't see how this would guarantee that one time stamp isn't the same as the last one. If you execute this code twice in less than one second, it will have the same value twice.

Further more, it's possible for the system clock to be adjusted while your code is running, and that could make this timestamp go backward.

Comment: If you want a time value in seconds, `Date.now() / 1000 | 0` is a lot less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you said you only do a new request every 10 seconds, so my comment about less that once per second shouldn't apply.

The clock being adjusted shouldn't be a frequent issue, but it can happen if your computer's time is synced to a time server, and its internal clock isn't very accurate, so bigger-than-10-second adjustments are needed now and then when the system clock is re-synced.

The only way to fix that problem (if that is the problem) is to track the last timestamp you issued, and do something like this:

```
let lastTimestamp = 0; // Outside of the function wrapping the code below
   //
const timestamp = Math.max(Math.round(Date.now() / 1000), lastTimestamp + 1);
lastTimestamp = timestamp;
```